# Can I retrieve the location of a phone number with Twilio?

Tags: geolocation, twilio

I'm working on a project that uses the Twilio API to send and receive text messages, but I'd like to be able to show the location of those cellular users in a table on my customer's dashboard.

In short, I'm looking for the data that shows up when you're shopping for a phone number on Twilio and it tells you it's from Newport Beach, California, etc.

Is there any way to retrieve that information from Twilio for a number besides one that is available for purchase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio Evangelist here. When Twilio makes a request to your server using a web hook, the [SMS](http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/twilio_request) and [voice](http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/twilio_request) will sometimes have geographical information.

- FromCity
- FromState
- FromZip
- FromCountry

But this information is not always available. There is no facility in the API to allow you to look up these outside of this context.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! It looks like this only applies when a text message is received to a Twilio number. Is that accurate?

Comment: This data can be available on both SMS and Voice, but I like to think of it as a 'best endeavour' by Twilio to provide the info. It will not always be available...